# C# Decimal Division (Extremely strange behavior)

Tags: c#, decimal, division

Can anyone explain this?

```
Decimal leftSide = 13.0M;
Decimal rightSide = 1.0M;
Decimal tmpDec = 39.0M;

tmpDec * (rightSide / leftSide) = 2.9999999999999999999999999991

tmpDec * rightSide / leftSide = 3
```

Am I losing significant digits on the first's (rightSide / leftSide)?

Comment: [what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Thank you for the white paper link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rounding (loosing precision) problem.

First case first executes division and crops the last digits (after 28th after decimal point since float (or double or decimal or any other fixed-precision data type) can't store the infinite long values), then executes multiplication of the cropped value, increasing the loss in 39 million times. That already becomes significant (it's not 28th digit issue now, nut 20-22nd) and can't be rounded to 3.0.

The second case first executes multiplication which don't loose precision and stores every 8 digits, then executes division with less precision loose (by 6 decimal points). So rounding already rounds to 3.0 and not to 2.999999999999999999999 as in fist case.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, you have confirmed my suspicion.

Answer (score 2):

The Decimal type is only precise to 29 significant digits.

`2.9999999999999999999999999991`

^ Has more than 29 significant digits.

You can use [System.Numerics.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) (modify it to work as fixed point decimal) if you require more precision.

Answer (score 0):

Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits requires an approximate representation. Although there are infinitely many integers, in most programs the result of integer computations can be stored in 32 bits. In contrast, given any fixed number of bits, most calculations with real numbers will produce quantities that cannot be exactly represented using that many bits. Therefore the result of a floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order to fit back into its finite representation. This rounding error is the characteristic feature of floating-point computation